# If every $A_i$ contains some $B_j$, then $\cap B_j \subseteq \cap A_i$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $ \{ A_i \}_{i\in I} $ and $ \{ B_j \}_{j\in J} $ be two indexed families of sets. Show that if $ \forall i \in I \exists j \in J$ such that $B_j \subseteq A_i $, then $ \bigcap_{j \in J } B_j \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I } A_i $

This is how I started:

$$ x \notin \bigcap_{i \in I } A_i \implies \neg(x \in \bigcap_{i \in I } A_i) $$
$$ \implies \neg(\forall i \in I x \in A_i) \implies \exists i \in I x \notin A_i $$
$$ \implies \exists j \in J x \notin B_j $$
$$ \equiv \forall j \in J x \in B_j \implies \forall i \in I x \in A_i $$
$$ \equiv x \in \bigcap_{j \in J } B_j \implies x \in \bigcap_{i \in I } A_i $$

Is this correct?

Comment: The third line comes from the given that every set $A$ has some subset $B$. The forth line is the contrapositive of the last two propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have is correct. The step
$$ \exists i \in I x \notin A_i \implies \exists j \in J x \notin B_j, $$
as you say, comes from the fact that every $A_i$ contains some $B_j$. So if $x$ is not in $A_i$, then that $A_i$ contains some $B_j$, and $x$ must not be in $B_j$ either.

---

Keep in mind that proofs written out in symbols are generally a lot harder to read than those written in words; most readers (and graders :) ) will appreciate more words.

**Proof in words:** 
Let $x \in \cap B_j$ be an arbitrary element of the intersection.
We want to show $x \in \cap A_i$, so we must show that $x \in A_i$ for all $i \in I$.

Now, fix some $i \in I$. By the condition we are given, there is a $j \in J$ such that $B_{j} \subseteq A_i$. Since $x \in \bigcap_{j' \in J} B_{j'}$, in particular $x \in B_j$. Therefore $x \in A_i$. $\square$